# I get error: "Overload resolution ambiguity" from MapElements transform in Apache Beam when using Kotlin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm exploring Apache Beam dataflow templates provided by GoogleCloudPlatform on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates).

In particular, I'm converting the [PubSubToBigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) template from Java into Kotlin.

By doing so, I get an *Overload ambiguity resolution* error in the `MapElements.input(...).via(...)` transform on line `274`. The error message is:

```
Error:(62, 22) Kotlin: Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference: 
public final fun <NewInputT : Any!> via(fn: ((input: BigQueryInsertError!) -> FailsafeElement<String!, String!>!)!): MapElements<BigQueryInsertError!, FailsafeElement<String!, String!>!>! defined in org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements
public final fun <NewInputT : Any!> via(fn: ((input: BigQueryInsertError!) -> FailsafeElement<String!, String!>!)!): MapElements<BigQueryInsertError!, FailsafeElement<String!, String!>!>! defined in org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements
```

The relevant Java code snippet is:

```
/*
     * Step 3 Contd.
     * Elements that failed inserts into BigQuery are extracted and converted to FailsafeElement
     */
    PCollection<FailsafeElement<String, String>> failedInserts =
        writeResult
            .getFailedInsertsWithErr()
            .apply(
                "WrapInsertionErrors",
                MapElements.into(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER.getEncodedTypeDescriptor())
                    .via((BigQueryInsertError e) -> wrapBigQueryInsertError(e)))
            .setCoder(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER);
```

The Kotlin conversion looks like:

```
/*
     * Step 3 Contd.
     * Elements that failed inserts into BigQuery are extracted and converted to FailsafeElement 
     */
val failedInserts: PCollection<FailsafeElement<String, String>> =
            writeResult.failedInsertsWithErr
            .apply(
                "WrapInsertionErrors",
                MapElements.into(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER.encodedTypeDescriptor)
                    .via { e: BigQueryInsertError -> wrapBigQueryInsertError(e) })
            .setCoder(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER)
```

I do not know how to resolve this. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the overload rules are slightly different between Java and Kotlin, which means that in Kotlin there are *two* matching overloads;

```
public <NewInputT> MapElements<NewInputT, OutputT> via(ProcessFunction<NewInputT, OutputT> fn)

public <NewInputT> MapElements<NewInputT, OutputT> via(SerializableFunction<NewInputT, OutputT> fn)
```

The simplest fix is to just explicitly specify the lambda as a `SerializableFunction` to get the correct overload;

```
.via<BigQueryInsertError> (SerializableFunction { e: BigQueryInsertError -> wrapBigQueryInsertError(e) }))
```